# Retrieve orientation info for video under Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, orientation

Just like `ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION`'s working for JPEG, how can I retrieve orientation info for video ?

For example I record a video in portrait mode, the orientation of video should be 90 or 270.

And when I record a video in landscape mode, the value should be 0 or 180.

When playing video, `MediaPlayer` in SDK always works correctly, but I don't find any way to retrieve this info.

Finally, if I cannot get orientation of video using android SDK, can I get this info using FFMPEG ?

Thanks very much for your help~

Comment: Any progress with the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19970372/874752 try this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using FFmpeg:

```
$ ffprobe -show_streams input.avi | grep rotate
TAG:rotate=90
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [blog post](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/tag/mp3/) that shows how to get the metadata of a media file. All functionality requires API level >= 10 though.