# Detect orientation of a recorded video in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, orientation, javacv

I want to make my custom media player and requires orientation info of video (for detecting it is recorded from front or back camera). for jpeg images i can use `ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION` but for video how i can find this information.

I tried to grab frame from video file and convert it into jpeg but again it always provides orientation `0` in all cases.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After too much effort i came to know that media player provides height and width of video file from which we can fin out rotation of video.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
  try {
      mp.setDataSource(viewSource);
      mp.prepare();
      mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

              int orientation = -1;

              if(width < height){
                  orientation = 0;
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);}
              else{
                  orientation = 1;
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);}

          }
      });
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: isn't this way is buggy, I understood that in KitKat the callback doesn't get called at all.

Comment: that's excetly what I'm saying. But I'm basing it on what I read in forums without checking it

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach can't help when video is rotated to 180 degrees

Comment: I get it to work sometimes, then it says "video can't play". So I agree, it is buggy. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: It is not working on the samsung device. I have checked on Samsung S5762.

Answer (score 23):

Api level 17 later, we can extract the orientation of video: [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

```
MediaMetadataRetriever m = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

m.setDataSource(path);
Bitmap thumbnail = m.getFrameAtTime();
//
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    String s = m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);

    Log.e("Rotation", s);
}
```

Comment: I tried using `String height = m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
            String width = m.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);` but all my videos are coming out the same size, whether they are in landscape or portrait. So this answer is very good. We must base the orientation check on the rotation. Thank you!

Comment: for me s is coming 0 any solution?

Comment: 0 is the rotation of your video, it can be `0`, `90`, `180` or `270`. People using this should know that the rotation tag might not always be available.

Answer (score 3):

[FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) can do this and it works with API 7+:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever fmmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
fmmr.setDataSource(path);
String rotation = fmmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);
Log.e("Rotation", rotation);
fmmr.release();
```

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but for what it's worth - the FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever library is massive - unless using build flavors, this will add about 18MB to your app. Unless you absolutely need the orientation of a video on API 16 or less, I would recommend not using this.

Comment: The library also offers prebuilt AAR's for each architecture, you can make individual APK's.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann It would be great if your library could provide the correct width and height.